# Lots of jquery-centric Dom work going on in directives link function - is this wrong?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing my very first directive - a simple popover that displays some content on mouseover (or on touch). It seems that my link function is basically a wrapper for some functionality I'd otherwise just bung in to a function in jquery world. Is this correct - wondering if there might be a more angular-centric way of achieving this?

http://jsfiddle.net/wx8ydotr/4/

```
core.directive('popover', ['isTouchDevice', function (isMobileDevice) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.addClass("popover");
        if (isMobileDevice) {
            el.bind("touchstart", function (e) {
                show();

            });
        } else {
            el.bind("mouseover", function (e) {
                show();

            });
             el.bind("mouseout", function (e) {
                hide();

            });
        }

        function show() {
         el.find('div').addClass('show');

        }

        function hide() {
            el.find('div').removeClass('show');            
        }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to forget about jQuery when working with Angular. Instead of adding classes like you do, you could use the `ng-class` as suggested by @swazza85 or then simply ready-made directives `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `ng-mouseover` or `ng-touch`.

Fastest & easiest way to achieve what you have now would be

```
<div ng-mouseover="show = true" ng-mouseleave="show = false">Some text</div>
<div ng-show="show">Initially hidden</div>
```

Unfortunately there is no directive capturing `touchstart` event, but you can work around it by binding these events in directive's `link` function, as you have done already.

One way to write your intention more angular way, wrapped as directive, could be the following.

HTML template

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
  <pop content="vm.val1" hover="vm.val2"></pop>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function() {
  this.val1 = 'Touch or move mouse over the label';
  this.val2 = '...I haz appeared!!1';
});

app.directive('pop', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { 
      content: '=', 
      hover: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-mouseover="toggle(true)" ng-mouseleave="toggle(false)">' +
              '  <h4><span class="label label-default">{{ content }}</span></h4>' +
              '</div>' + 
              '<div ng-show="show" class="alert alert-info">{{ hover }}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.toggle = function(val) {
        scope.show = val;
      };

      element.bind('touchstart', toggle, true);
      element.bind('touchend', toggle, false);
    }
  };
});
```

[image: imgur]

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/JjydPL

Comment: Great answer thanks, learnt a lot from that! I was hacking around with something based on Swazza85's answer but this has filled in the gaps for me.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents, I would suggest to make your html more declarative. Try and represent your view as a model and initialize your model in the link function.

As an example, consider the below HTML snippet

```
<div ng-class="{ 'fade-in': showResults, 'fade-out': !showResults }"></div>
```

The showResults variable is bound to the $scope that can be accessed in your directive's link function. Depending on the conditions, you might want to set -

```
$scope.showResults = true/false;
```

in your link function. Doing so makes your view more declarative and instead of operating on the DOM, you are representing your DOM as a view model and operating on the view model.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Yes that is helpful and it does do away with the Dom manip in the show/hide functions. Don't suppose there is any way to do away with the event listeners...

Comment: Also wondering to make things clean could I inject something similar to what you have above (the bit that uses ng-class) using the template functionality in the directive?...just wanting to keep the work needed in the html to a minimum.

Comment: yes, instead of using the 'template' property, you can contain your html in a partial view and specify the url to that partial view in the 'templateUrl' property. As to binding DOM events that haven't already been covered by angular (ex - ngClick, ngMouseover, etc), I suppose el.bind is the way to go.